# Forward substitution packed array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, linear-algebra

So I'm trying to create a script that will take an array, transform it into packed form, then run the Cholesky factorisation against it and finally use forward and backward substitution to solve it (`Ax=b`).

The trouble im having is creating the forward substitution (column wise) algorithm for packed arrays. I've got the backward substitution done correctly, however I cannot seem to transform the algorithm correctly.

This is the current backward substitution algorithm I have (which is perfect)

```
x = b;
p = n*(n+1)/2;

for j = n:-1:1
  x(j) = x(j) / u(p);
  p = p - 1;
  for i = j-1:-1:1
    x(i) = x(i) - u(p) * x(j);
    p = p - 1;
  end
end
```

Where `n` is the size of the original `A` matrix (which is square and SPD). The mapping from the `A` matrix to `u` is as follows:

```
A(i,j) = u(i+j*(j-1)/2)
```

My current iteration of the forward substitution algorithm is as follows:

```
x = b;
p = 1;

for j = 1:n
    x(j) = x(j) / u(p);
    p = p + 1;
    for i = j+1:n
        x(i) = x(i) - u(p) * x(j);
        p = p + 1;
    end
end
```

I cannot seem to work out what I'm doing wrong. Whatever I try ends up just giving me `NaN` or `Inf` as answers for `x`. Can anyone smarter than me work out what the algorithm should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to solve two problems that result in the solution of `Ax = b`.

Where `A = LL'` that is to say `A` is equal to a Lower Triangular Matrix (`L`) multiplied by its Transpose (`L'`)

Firstly by solving `Ly = b` with forward substitution.

Finally by solving `L'x = y` with back substitution.

Where for your back substituion your `u(p)` is defined as such (for n =3):

```
     | u(1) u(2) u(4) |
L' = |  0   u(3) u(5) |
     |  0    0   u(6) |
```

The issue I think you're running into with the forward substition comes form what `L` would be defined as:

```
    | u(1)  0    0   |
L = | u(2) u(3)  0   |
    | u(4) u(5) u(6) |
```

Your value `p` would need to have the following progression to accomplish what you want with the forward substition:

`{1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6}`

I have modified your current code for forward subtitution to impliment this pattern.

```
x = b;
p = 1;

for j = 1:n
    d = j-1;
    p = j + (d^2+d)/2;
    x(j) = x(j) / u(p);
    d = d + 1;
    for i = j+1:n
        p = j + (d^2+d)/2;
        x(i) = x(i) - u(p) * x(j);
        d = d + 1;
    end
end
```

I was able to test this, and it produces an expected result.
I hope that this helps you.